# upload video via upload widget

Tags: html, youtube, html5-video, youtube-api

Hi I am new to web designing. I am creating a code where a user can upload a video from his PC to YouTube. I am using the Google video upload widget. But its only giving me an option to record a video from a web cam. I am not getting an option to browse and select videos from my documents (PC). Please can I get some help? Or is there any other method to upload videos to YouTube and get its url or id? I need it so as an admin I can save it in database to view the videos later.
Here's my code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>  
    <div id="widget"></div>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>   
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);    
      var widget;
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
          width: 500,
          events: {
            'onUploadSuccess': onUploadSuccess,
            'onProcessingComplete': onProcessingComplete
          }
        });
      }      
      function onUploadSuccess(event) {
        alert('Video ID ' + event.data.videoId + ' was uploaded and is currently being processed.');
      }
      function onProcessingComplete(event) {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: 390,
          width: 640,
          videoId: event.data.videoId,
          events: {}
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
          width: 500,
          events: {
            'onUploadSuccess': onUploadSuccess,
            'onProcessingComplete': onProcessingComplete
          }
        });
```

to this:

```
widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
      width: 500,
      webcamOnly: false,
      events: {
        'onUploadSuccess': onUploadSuccess,
        'onProcessingComplete': onProcessingComplete
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is no longer possible with the upload widget because they have removed the feature.  I have confirmed that even if you set "webcamOnly: false" as an option the upload button that is displayed actually does not do anything.

See their changelog: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget#Revision_History

> "The webcamOnly property has been removed from the list of widget options that you can specify in the constructor for the upload widget. Previously, this property was documented as having a default value of false, which would mean that the widget would also display a button for uploading an existing video file. However, **the option to upload an existing file is not currently supported**, so the widget always only displays an option to record and upload a webcam video."